# mysql update based on time stamp in another column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-workbench

```
+------+------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
| SEQ  | ID   |instamp         |outstamp        | duration |
+------+------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
| 2516 |    1 |2020-02-22 14:22:47 |2020-02-22 14:24:06 |     NULL |
| 2517 |    1 |2020-02-22 14:24:08 |2020-02-22 14:24:27 |     NULL |
| 2518 |    1 |2020-02-22 14:24:28 |2020-02-22 14:24:47 |     NULL |
| 2519 |    1 |2020-02-22 14:24:48 |2020-02-22 14:25:06 |     NULL |
| 2520 |    1 |2020-02-22 14:25:08 |2020-02-24 23:14:00 |     NULL |
```

I am trying to update the last duration parameter.
if I do

```
"mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,outTimestamp,intimestamp) from sTable;
```

This is working. but I am not able to update the last column.

I tried

```
update sTable rt set duration = (select TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, outstamp,instamp) from sTable rt1 where rt1.outstamp is not null and rt.seq = rt1.seq) ;
```

This is giving an error. can you please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Suggest when you have a question about a statement giving an error, you actually include the full error text in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Update clause it not correct.
It must be

```
UPDATE sTable rt SET duration = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, outstamp,instamp) 
WHERE rt.outstamp IS NOT nulL;
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE sTable (
>   `SEQ` INTEGER,
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `instamp` datetime,
>   `outstamp` datetime,
>   `duration` INTEGER 
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO sTable
>   (`SEQ`, `ID`, `instamp`, `outstamp`, `duration`)
> VALUES
>   ('2516', '1', '2020-02-22 14:22:47', '2020-02-22 14:24:06', NULL),
>   ('2517', '1', '2020-02-22 14:24:08', '2020-02-22 14:24:27', NULL),
>   ('2518', '1', '2020-02-22 14:24:28', '2020-02-22 14:24:47', NULL),
>   ('2519', '1', '2020-02-22 14:24:48', '2020-02-22 14:25:06', NULL),
>   ('2520', '1', '2020-02-22 14:25:08', '2020-02-24 23:14:00', NULL);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,outstamp,instamp) from sTable;
> ```
>
> ```
> | TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,outstamp,instamp) |
> | -------------------------------------: |
> |                                     -1 |
> |                                      0 |
> |                                      0 |
> |                                      0 |
> |                                  -3408 |
> ```

> ```
> update sTable rt set duration = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, outstamp,instamp) 
> where rt.outstamp is not null ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM sTable;
> ```
>
> ```
>  SEQ | ID | instamp             | outstamp            | duration
> ---: | -: | :------------------ | :------------------ | -------:
> 2516 |  1 | 2020-02-22 14:22:47 | 2020-02-22 14:24:06 |       -1
> 2517 |  1 | 2020-02-22 14:24:08 | 2020-02-22 14:24:27 |        0
> 2518 |  1 | 2020-02-22 14:24:28 | 2020-02-22 14:24:47 |        0
> 2519 |  1 | 2020-02-22 14:24:48 | 2020-02-22 14:25:06 |        0
> 2520 |  1 | 2020-02-22 14:25:08 | 2020-02-24 23:14:00 |    -3408
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=73d2a90b76e09d8c7825d1666de953b3)*